# Soft reset assembly instruction in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, qemu

IS it possible to do a soft reset in x86, I mean if there is an assembly instruction that. Basically I want to do a soft reset after an exception happens ( after the execution of the handler) ?

Comment: No, there is not a specific instruction. You would have to mimic the hardware reset process, unless your OS has a soft reset entry point.For example, MS-DOS `int 19h` performs a warm boot.

Comment: You can also triple fault ;) But it's not clear what you mean by soft reset...

Comment: You might be able to get some information from this [SO question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682152/how-to-reboot-in-x86-assembly-from-16-bit-real-mode).